# How to write text to a server-side file

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, save

So I'm trying to get my webpage to save some text to a server-side file. It's kinda like a guestbook, but I want it in a text file so I can review it before I put it on the site. I've been looking around, and from the looks of it, you can't do it with javascript because of 'security hazards'. I've seen things about php, but php files never seem to work for me. Is there a way to do this in plain .html and if not how do I make a php file do this, and be very specific with the steps required to make said php file. And I'm using apache if that helps at all. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take one PHP file and *is not secure*.  But, it is what you want.  The user can very easily sign the guest book.  Additionally, it will display previous guest entries on the page.  Yay!

**guestBook.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['posts'])) {
        $_SESSION['posts'] = 0;
    } else if ($_SESSION['posts'] >= 5) {
        echo "<div style='color:red'>Failed to post - max posts exceded</div>";
    }   else {
        $_SESSION['posts'] += 1;
        file_put_contents("guest.txt",htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) . "<br />",FILE_APPEND);
    }    
}
echo file_get_contents("guest.txt");

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="John Kieth" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

P.S.  You literally can't do this through regular HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: okay I'll try it, but what do I do from the html file? Like how do I call the php file. Also what security risks are there with doing this?

Comment: Basically, you install a software that can run PHP files.  Like, WAMP.  http://www.wampserver.com/en/ , then you install the files to the proper location and access them through localhost/ .  Note:  this file is all self contained.  You only need one file to run this program.  This is the only file you need.  Additionally, I updated the php code to secure against most injections and etc.  Finally, if you could please upvote/mark as answer that would help a lot.

Comment: I'm currently trying it out (downloading wamp as I type this.) But before I click the check mark, there are two things:
1: I need to test it obviously
2: what was different about the first php you submitted that made it insecure? I noticed you added htmlspecialchars

Comment: HTML is your primary enemy when it comes to saving this information to a backend file.  By removing HTML tags (via the htmlspecialchars function), we are now able to avoid people inserting malicious JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: makes sense

little side note, (wamp still downloading... crap internet) will this only run in software like wamp, because I tried opening it with my browser, just the file by itself and it displayed just as text.

Comment: Yeah, for server-side languages you need a server.  Just wait, finish downloading it, and see if it works.

Comment: okay it works! Now I just gotta figure out a way to limit the amount of times someone can hit submit heh

Comment: Post another question and link it here, I could find a way of doing it.

Comment: Never mind, it was actually a really easy fix, I updated the code

Comment: It limits the number of posts to 5

Comment: does stackoverflow have any form of Private Messaging?

Comment: sorry, link expired. new one?